# -bash: open: command not found

Tags: macos, cordova, command-line, bash

I was working on amending my `ANDROID_HOME` and `PATH` to begin working with Cordova for mobile application development. I was having trouble with `export $PATH` returning a `not a valid identifier` error. I changed a `$PATH` reference in a line in the `.bash_profile` to `PATH` on recommendation and now I'm entirely unable to `open .bash_profile`. I am using Mac OS X Yosemite. I receive the following error:

`-bash: open: command not found`

From research, it's likely a typo in the `.bash_profile` but I'm unaware of how I can rectify this without being able to open the .bash_profile itself, can anybody help? Also when attempting to call Cordova e.g. `cordova add platform android` I receive `-bash: cordova: command not found` after it previously functioned correctly?

My `.bash_profile` included 
`export ANDROID_HOME=/Development/android-sdk-macosx export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`

I believe I mistakenly removed $ from the 2nd line, leaving `PATH={PATH}.`

As I am using Mac OS X all dot files are hidden, when attempting to show . files I receive the error `-bash: defaults: command not found`.

Thanks

Comment: You export a variable *name* not its contents. So `export PATH` not `export $PATH`.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for directing me towards this post. I am now able to access the `.bash_profile` once more!

Answer (score 1):

`export $PATH` doesn't do what you expect - variable substitution happens *before* command execution in Bash. You need to `export PATH`. And to debug the contents of any dot files you need to include their contents in the question.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My apologies, I'm still learning the ropes here! The contents were:

`export ANDROID_HOME=/Development/android-sdk-macosx
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`
I believe I mistakenly removed $ from the 2nd line, leaving PATH={PATH}.

Comment: Thank you. I have done this.

Answer (score 0):

Having destroyed your `PATH` environment variable your shell can no longer find any binaries. You can either give a full path to whatever application you want to run to edit your `.bash_profile` file or just open it from your chosen editor using the gui file selector.

Comment: Thank you. I neglected to mention I am using Mac OS X so all . files are hidden. When attempting to show . files I receive the error `-bash: defaults: command not found`. Can you recommend another way to access and edit the `.bash_profile`?